# Create a table with table keys in Lua with the C API

Tags: lua

In Lua, you can create a table whose keys are themselves tables:

```
t = {}
t[{1,2}] = 2
```

I would like to know how to do the analogous thing using the C API. That is, I am writing a C function callable from Lua, which will return a table with table keys. I tried to push a table as a key and then use lua_settable, but it seems to do nothing.

**Edit:** Relevant code:

```
lua_createtable(L, 0, n);
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    // push the key table
    lua_createtable(L, 2, 0);
    for(j = 0; j < 2; ++j){
        lua_pushinteger(L, j+1);
        lua_pushinteger(L, j);
        lua_settable(L, -3);
    }
    // push the value table
    lua_createtable(L, 4, 0);
    for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
        lua_pushinteger(L, j+1);
        lua_pushnumber(L, j);
        lua_settable(L, -3);
    }
    lua_settable(L, -3);
}
```

**Edit**: I was being dumb; I used `lua_objlen(L, -1)` at the end to check on the size of the table, which returns 0 since there are no integer keyed entries. Also, in the Lua code that processed the table, I used `ipairs` instead of `pairs`. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was checking for the table entries in the wrong way. I have edited the question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing a table as the key and using lua_settable is the right thing to do. Most likely, you just forgot to also push on a value and did effectively t = { {} = nil }, which is of course nothing.